# Image button needs to be clicked twice to delete Fire store data & update UI in Android

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I am making a basic app using Kotlin & android studio which lets user store some data & display it in a fragment using a recycler view. I am storing the data on cloud Fire store. An image button (which is on each recycler view item) , when clicked ,is responsible for deleting data from fire store & updating the UI with modified data. The issue is I have to click this image button twice to implement deletion. Can someone find a fix

Following is the code of my image button.I am using constraint layouts, custom background & source for it->

```
<ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ibDelete"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/ibEdit"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvDescription"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/tvRating"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:src="@drawable/delete_white"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="-40dp"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.1"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias=".7"
                android:contentDescription="@string/imagebutton" />
```

My recycler view adapter. Basically I have created data class & uploaded those data classes in Firestore. I access those data classes via array List. The usual stuff ->

```
class PersonalMemoryAdapter(
    private val context : Context,
    private var list : ArrayList<Memory>,
    private var fragment:PersonalFragment) : RecyclerView.Adapter<PersonalMemoryAdapter.MyViewHolder>(){

    class MyViewHolder ( val binding : PersonalRvItemBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        return MyViewHolder(PersonalRvItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context),parent,false))
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val model = list[position]

        if(position%4==0){
            holder.binding.tvColor.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FECE2F"))
            holder.binding.tvColor.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FECE2F"))
        } else if(position%4==1){
            holder.binding.tvColor.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F999cd"))
            holder.binding.tvColor.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#F999cd"))

        } else if(position%4==2){
            holder.binding.tvColor.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#9ACD32"))
            holder.binding.tvColor.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#9ACD32"))
        }else{
            holder.binding.tvColor.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F5DEB3"))
            holder.binding.tvColor.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#F5DEB3"))
        }

        GlideLoader(context).loadPicture(model.imageURL,holder.binding.ivCircleImage)
        holder.binding.tvTitle.text=model.title
        holder.binding.tvCityName.text="${model.cityName[0].toString().toUpperCase()}${model.cityName.substring(1)}"
        holder.binding.tvDescription.text=model.description
        holder.binding.tvRating.text=model.rating.toString()
        holder.itemView.tvDate.text=model.date

        holder.binding.ibDelete.setOnClickListener{
            fragment.deleteProduct(model.memoryID)
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return list.size
    }
    

}
```

Some part of my fragment activity . Certain functions like ->

```
private var mBinding : FragmentPersonalBinding? = null

override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        getListFromFireStore()
    }

    private fun getListFromFireStore(){
        showProgressDialog()
        FireStoreClass().getMemoriesList(this)
    }

    fun listReceivedSuccessfully(memoryList: ArrayList<Memory>) {
        hideProgressBar()
        if(memoryList.size>0){
            mBinding!!.rvPersonal.visibility=View.VISIBLE
            mBinding!!.tvPersonal.visibility=View.GONE

            mBinding!!.rvPersonal.layoutManager=LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
            val rvAdapter=PersonalMemoryAdapter(requireContext(),memoryList,this)
            mBinding!!.rvPersonal.adapter=rvAdapter

        }else{
            mBinding!!.rvPersonal.visibility=View.GONE
            mBinding!!.tvPersonal.visibility=View.VISIBLE
        }
    }

    fun deleteProduct(memoryID: String) {
        showProgressDialog()
        FireStoreClass().deleteMemory(this, memoryID)
    }

    fun deleteSuccessful() {
        hideProgressBar()
        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Deleted Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        getListFromFireStore()
    }
```

My Fire store class ->

```
private val mFireStore =FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    fun getMemoriesList(fragment : PersonalFragment){
            mFireStore.collection(Constants.MEMORIES)
                .whereEqualTo(Constants.USERID,getCurrentUserID())
                .get()
                .addOnSuccessListener { list->
                    val memoryList : ArrayList<Memory> = ArrayList()
                    for(i in list.documents){
                        val memory =i.toObject(Memory::class.java)!!
    
                        val memoryHashmap = HashMap<String,Any>()
                        memoryHashmap[Constants.MEMORY_ID]=i.id
                        mFireStore.collection(Constants.MEMORIES)
                            .document(i.id)
                            .update(memoryHashmap)
    
                        memoryList.add(memory)
                    }
    
                    fragment.listReceivedSuccessfully(memoryList)
    
                }
                .addOnFailureListener {
                    fragment.hideProgressBar()
                }
        }
    
        fun deleteMemory(fragment: PersonalFragment,memoryID:String,){
            mFireStore.collection(Constants.MEMORIES)
                .document(memoryID)
                .delete()
                .addOnSuccessListener {
                    fragment.deleteSuccessful()
                }
                .addOnFailureListener {
                    fragment.hideProgressBar()
                    Log.e(fragment.javaClass.simpleName, "Error while deleting the memory.",)
                }
        }
```

Comment: I think that this article, [How to delete a record from Firestore on a RecylerView left/right swipe?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-delete-a-record-from-firestore-on-a-recylerview-left-right-swipe-d65d993f0baf) or [How to delete multiple records from Firestore using RecyclerView multi-selection?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-delete-multiple-records-from-firestore-using-recyclerview-multi-selection-96108e4c6166) might help.

Comment: What is actually happening when you first time click the button the corresponds to a single item?

Comment: When I click t once , my toast "deleted successfully"  is shown. This is weird because it means it processed all the firebase functions but didn't do anything. .

Comment: Do you see the item as deleted in the Firebase Console?

Comment: No, its neither deleted from the firebase console nor deleted from the UI

Comment: Is your onSuccess or onFailure even triggered?

Comment: Log.e("Deleted","DONE") I added this in the onSuccess event of the function which deletes the data and surprisingly it was shown in the logcat on a single click

Comment: So that's no issue anymore, right?

Comment: It just shows the message in the logcat but still neither the data is deleted nor the UI is changed. 2nd click also shows the log message along with deleting data

Comment: NOTE - Just found out that this but is only present when I try to delete the 1st element of the recycler view. Works well for other elements